# Win32Com Opening Excel in Background, Not Visible, Can't Run Macros

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, win32com

The following code in Python is not opening excel visibly on my device, and excel launches as a background process instead of an app.

```
import win32com.client

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.visible = True
excel.DisplayAlerts = True

workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add()
```

I expect excel to open visibly, for me to be able to watch all operations being performed, and for excel to function much as if it were being opened manually. When the code executed, no excel workbook has been opened on my screen. I examine task manager and notice that excel is open only as a background task. Attempting to perform certain other operations in the open workbook fail because the program is not visible. I get no error codes from the above code, but I have more code dependent on excel being launched visibly as an app. I run the same code on other devices and experience no such issue. Why might the excel app not be launching as an app?

Comment: You may have an instance of Excel already running in the background in some error state. Your Dispatch call may be attaching to this stalled process ... kill the background process and try again.

Comment: I have killed all instances of excel, both applications and background processes.

Comment: Well `excel.visible = True` should give an error the correct syntax is `excel.Visible = True`, upper case 'V'. Otherwise should work

Comment: @moken There won't necessarily be an error from `visible` depending how `win32com` has created the dispatch interface.